# Javascript Bind function to Ajax load event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter

I am trying to write an chrome extension that interacts with Twitter pages however I am having a hard time firing off the function when the twitter stream is ready because it is dynamically loaded after the document is ready.

How can I bind a function to the element being loaded or some sort of generic ajax success response for the element.

current code.
https://github.com/billpull/Twitter-Ticker

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [`.ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/), which is a global handler that is executed when an ajax call is successful (provided the ajax call was done through `.ajax`).